# Single signon framework for multiple cloud products we control?

Tags: .net, single-sign-on

So we have a cloud product that requires a username and password.

We are going to be launching another product that also uses a username nad password.

We're a .net / sql server shop.

Is there a standard or any easy to implement 3rd party solutions designed for this sort of situation?  Or do we need to roll our own?

If we rolled our own I guess we'd:

1. take all the usernames from product 1
2. use it to create a new master database which tells us which products the user is licensed for
3. modify the login logic for both app A and app B to reference this master database.

In the future we will probably add app C and D.

Is there a standard approach for attacking this problem?

Using facebook connect is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAML (http://saml.xml.org/) is a popular choice to solve such a dilemma.  SAML defines single sign on profiles that allow user authentications to be trusted between desparate systems.  You could for example have your own SAML login IdP (Identity Provider), and then all your apps act as SPs (Service Providers).  Many popular cloud apps (such as Google Apps and Salesforce.com) and frameworks (such as MS WIF) support SAML today.

Comment: Yeah I've looked at SAML.  I guess my question was more around actual implementations of it.  i.e. is there a commonly used library or SDK for implementing SAML between two .net apps?  I could make our master product contain the main user database, and then pass SAML tokens to my 2ndry and tertiary apps... but I'd love it if there was a well documented library I could leverage in pursuit of that

Comment: Microsoft Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) has support for SAML 2.0 tokens, but you need to fill in some blanks to completely implement the protocol portion.  A few other vendors (such as Ping Identity, and ComponentSpace) offer popular plugins and libraries for the .NET platform.

Comment: Awesome scott - thanks.  this gives me a starting point.  If you've worked with any of these, do you have a recommendation?

Comment: If you have a budget, Ping Identity would be a good simple choice and make life easier for future growth.  If you have .NET developers, lots of time and no budget - WIF could work.